# Integration of an asymptotic equivalence.

Tags: integration, limits, asymptotics

If $f(x)$ is differentiable for $0<x<1$ and if the following asymptotic equivalence holds:
$$f'(x)\sim \log x \ \ \  \text{as}\ \ \ x\to 1^-\tag{1}$$
**Question** Does $(1)$ imply that $f(x)\sim \int \log x\  dx \ \ \  \text{as}\ \ \ x\to 1^-$

Note that $\log x$ is unbounded in $(0,1)$.

**Edit** In this post: [Can I integrate an asymptotic expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807035/can-i-integrate-an-asymptotic-expression)     the second answer with no upvotes says it is possible.
But in another post there is a counterexample: [Integrating an asymptotic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88699/integrating-an-asymptotic/88701)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you could try to show is that $f(x) \sim  - \int_x^1 \log t\,dt$ as $x\to 1-$.

Comment: @Gary Thats nice. But how can we show that? Please write a short answer. I will accept the answer.

Comment: I missed a $+f(1)$ on the right-hand side. Note that $$
f(x) - \left( { - \int_x^1 {\log t\,dt}  + f(1)} \right) =  - \int_x^1 {(f'(t) - \log t)dt} .
$$ Can you show that the right-hand side is $$
o\!\left( {\int_x^1 {\log t\,dt} } \right)
$$ as $x\to 1-$?

Comment: @Gary I am sorry. I could not follow.l your last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show that
$$
f(x) - f(1) =  - \int_x^1 {\log t\,dt}  + o\!\left( {\left| {\int_x^1 {\log t\,dt} } \right|} \right)
$$
as $x\to 1^-$, i.e.,
$$
f(x) - f(1) \sim  - \int_x^1 {\log t\,dt} 
$$
as $x\to 1^-$. Note that for $0<x<1$, we have
$$
f(x) - f(1) =  - \int_x^1 {\log t\,dt}  - \int_x^1 {(f'(t) - \log t)dt} .
$$
Now, by assumption, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta$ such that
$$ |f'(x)-\log x|\leq \varepsilon|\log x|$$ if $0<1-x<\delta$. Choosing such $\delta$ for a fixed $\varepsilon>0$ then gives
$$
\left| {\int_x^1 {(f'(t) - \log t)dt} } \right| \le \int_x^1 {\left| {f'(t) - \log t} \right|dt}  \le \varepsilon \int_x^1 {\left| {\log t} \right|dt}  = \varepsilon \left| {\int_x^1 {\log t\,dt} } \right|,
$$
which is what we wanted to prove.